# Unexpected tokens (use ; to separate expressions in the same line)

Tags: kotlin

```
val a = 2
if (a==1 | a==2) {

}
```

This code doesnt compile - error "Unexpected tokens (use ; to separate expressions in the same line)

How to solve? why is that even a problem? and why do the tutorials not aware of that compilation error [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#kotlin) [image]?

[Kotlin playground with that code](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjcyIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHByaW50bG4oXCJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhISFcIilcbiAgICB2YWwgYSA9IDJcbiAgICBpZiAoYT09MSB8IGE9PTIpIHtcbiAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgfVxufSJ9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a mistake on translating it to kotlin.
if you look on the java part they use

```
if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
```

so in that case use or keyword or ;-) ||

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    val a = 2
    if ((a==1) or (a==2)) {
        println("fine")
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `||` -- it's the same as in Java, and which is always used unless you specifically need the non-short-circuit operation (or bitwise calculaton) that `or` gives (equivalent to `|` in Java).

Comment: i like the way kotlin is doing it much more, cause the ```or``` avoids exactly the confusion which lead to this question